# ajax request hidden fields

Tags: php, jquery

I'm developing a site (only for fun and learn programming with jquery)
and i'd like to know what's wrong with this :

```
$(window).unload(function(){
 var myid = $('input#v1').attr('value');   // hidden
 var playauth = $('input#v2').attr('value');   // hidden
 var srvid = $('input#v3').attr('value');      // hidden
 var result = 'myid='+ myid +'&auth='+ playauth +'&srvid='+ srvid;
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: result,
            url: "closing.php",
            complete: function(data) {
            alert(data.responseText);
            }
           });
});
```

I'm trying to update a database table. When i close the window nothing happens.
With a previous version of this function :

```
window.onunload = function () {
  var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var n = document.getElementById("v1").InnerHTML;
  var o = document.getElementById("v2").InnerHTML;
  var p = document.getElementById("v3").InnerHTML;
  xhReq.open("GET", ("closing.php?myid=" + n + "&auth=" + o + "&srvid=" + p) , false);
  xhReq.send(null);
  var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
  alert(serverResponse); 
};
```

.. i saw the response alert but GET values were 'undefined'.
 .... probably because the type of inputs is hidden..?
This is my form... maybe i miss something ?? I'm really new to jquery/ajax .. please help!!

```
<form method="get">
<input id="v1" type="hidden" name="val1" class="aget" value="<?php echo $_GET['myid']; ?>" />
<input id="v2" type="hidden" name="val2" class="bget" value="<?php echo $_GET['playauth']; ?>" />
<input id="v3" type="hidden" name="val3" class="cget" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['srvid']; ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: One word of warning, when firing ajax/xhttp calls off on the unload event there is no guarantee that the request will get through before it is cancelled as the browser closes down the page. It may be best to use `'onbeforeunload'` and to also set your ajax call to syncronous using the `async:false` parameter... I haven't ever attempted such a thing myself however.

Comment: your suggest was good... but the function doesn't work... do i have to put it inside the $(document).ready ... etc.. ?

Comment: Which function are you refering to that doesn't work? If you mean your `complete` callback then it may be that the browser blocks any further js from running directly after the syncronous ajax call ends... Are you getting `closing.php` called at least? Basically what you are attempting to do is always going to be tricky, especially if you are relying on doing further processing pretty much as the user wants to leave the page. Setting ajax calls to syncronous can also be slightly dangerous because if the request hangs for any reason, so will the browser.

Comment: ...got it! I put a semicolon instead of a comma inserting the row as suggested by pebbl.. now i got the response Thank you....

Comment: Ah, I see... good old syntax errors :) make sure you take in to account the other two answers.. you should be using .val() in your code if you want to be doing things the "jQuery way".. good luck with the project!

Comment: .. i'm trying to make the visitor of a specific page unable to reopen again it.. yes.. i'm going a to be tricky.. maybe there are better or faster solutions. Now i have to intercept the refresh event of the page because the window.unload functions is called when a user refreshes the page too.. and i don't want the script to be called .. thanks again

Comment: Ah I see, well whenever doing anything involving user tracking I'd definitely recomend using cookies (you can set and read them from JavaScript) or you can use it's more modern equivalent HTML5's localStorage. Using either of these methods would just involve storing some kind of value and then reading it back the next time the user visits the page (you wouldn't have to rely on ajax calls). Obviously both these methods are susceptible to the user clearing cookies or local storage however.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
 var myid = $('input#v1').attr('value');   // hidden
 var playauth = $('input#v2').attr('value');   // hidden
 var srvid = $('input#v3').attr('value');      // hidden
```

to

```
 var myid = $('input#v1').val();   // hidden
 var playauth = $('input#v2').val();   // hidden
 var srvid = $('input#v3').val();      // hidden
```

Comment: Nothing , i have the same result .. :(

Answer (score 2):

You must use

`.val();` instead of `.attr('value');`